# Bad file descriptor error while creating a concurrent server in a client-server app (UDP)

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I'm making a client-server app with udp with a concurrent server and I'm having some problems sending the information to the server.

Here's the code for the server:

```
#define SERV_UDP_PORT   6777

int main() {

int sockfd, newsockfd, clilen, n, pid_hijo;
struct sockaddr_in cli_addr, serv_addr ;
char host_name[200], buffer[1024];

if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0){
   perror("server: can't open datagram socket");
   exit(-1);
} /* if */


serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY) ;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERV_UDP_PORT);

if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) <0) {
    perror("server: can't bind local address") ;
    exit(-1);
} /* if */


for (;;) {
    // Create the new process for the concurrente server
    if ((pid_hijo=fork()) == 0) {
        servidor_hijo(sockfd);
        close(sockfd);
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        close(sockfd);
        while (wait((int *)0) != pid_hijo);
    }
}
}

int servidor_hijo(int sockfd) {

int n, clilen;
char buffer[1024];
struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;


// Inicializamos los buffers
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr) ;
bzero((char *)&cli_addr,clilen); /* debe inicializarse cli_addr antes del recvfrom */
bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));


if ((n=recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr,&clilen)) <0) {
    perror("secho: error en funcion recvfrom");
    exit(-1);
} /* if */


printf("\n\n%s (%d bytes)\n",buffer,n);

if ((n=sendto(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer),0, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr,clilen)) <0) {
    perror("secho: Error en funcion sendto");
    exit(-1);
}
}
```

And here's the code for the client

```
/* Cliente de ECO sobre UDP*/

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define SERV_UDP_PORT   6777

main() {
    int sockfd, n, clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr ;
    char serv_host_addr[30], buffer[1024];

    printf("Dirección IP del servidor (a.b.c.d) => ");
    gets(serv_host_addr);

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("client: can't open datagram socket") ;
        return -1;
    }


    bzero((char *)&cli_addr,sizeof(cli_addr)); /* puerto cero */
    cli_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,sizeof(cli_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("client: can't bind a port");
        exit(-1);
    } /* if */

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;
    inet_pton(AF_INET,serv_host_addr,&serv_addr.sin_addr);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERV_UDP_PORT) ;


    printf("Bienvenido al Servicio de ECO ==> "); 
    gets(buffer);

    clilen=sizeof(serv_addr);
    if ((n=sendto(sockfd, buffer,strlen(buffer),0, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,clilen)) <0) {
        perror("cecho: error en funcion sendto");
        exit(-1);
    } /* if */

    printf("cecho: envie %d bytes\n",n);

    bzero(buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    clilen = sizeof(serv_addr);

    if ((n=recvfrom(sockfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,&clilen)) < 0) {
        perror("cecho: error en funcion recvfrom");
        exit(-1);
    } /* if */
    printf("ECO> %s\n",buffer);
    close(sockfd);
    }
```

The function servidor_hijo is what makes the server concurrent to reply different request...

The problem is... When I execute the client app, it sends the packet to the server app, but the server doesn't send the response and prints on the screen an error message telling that has been a "Bad file descriptor error".

Could you help me with this?

Thank you all!!

Comment: First you have to open the socket with:
`udp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);`

Then try to find exactly in which point the bad file descriptor error is being generated. Is it inside the servidor_hijo function ? Where exactly ?

Comment: I've done that... :( don't know what is wrong :(

Comment: the error is generated in the recvfrom function.

Comment: Whatever happens, you should replace `exit(-1)` with `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`.  On many Unix systems, the possible range of values for return status codes in the shell is 0-255, with 0 meaning success and 1 being the typical value for failure (you'll probably find EXIT_FAILURE means 1).  Exiting with -1 will overflow and your shell will see the return code as 255, which is just confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (I would have to read up on fork and fd's otherwise) In the else of the fork remove the close, otherwise the socket gets closed that the other process wants to send data back.

hth

Mario

Comment: thanks! be careful though, I am not sure (and haven't found a quick answer goggeling) if this is really a good idea. At fork the fd's are dup()'ed, so it should also work.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling bind() and then fork().
You can't have two processes and two sockets bound to the same port.

I suggest you receive the packet and then fork() to process it.